# Diagonalizability of an endomorphism on polynoms

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ with $\deg B=n+1$. Let $\phi(P)$ be the remainder of the euclidian division of $AP$ by $B$.

a) Show that $\phi$ is an endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$ (I have done that one)

**b) We suppose that $B$ has $(n+1)$ distinct real roots. Show that $\phi$ is diagonalizable.**

---

What I have done :

$AP=BQ+\phi(P)$

Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{n+1}$ be the roots of $B$.

$(AP)(\lambda_i)=\phi(P)(\lambda_i)$ and that holds for $n+1$ values (whereas $\deg\phi( P)<n+1$).

Let $(AP)(\lambda_i)=\alpha_i$

Hence $\phi(P)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\alpha_i \prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{n+1}\dfrac{X-\lambda_j}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}$

We can then express its matrix in the base $L$ of the Lagrange polynomials :

$$\mathrm{mat}(\phi)_L=\begin{bmatrix}0&\alpha_2&\alpha_3&\dots&\alpha_n
\\\alpha_1&0&\alpha_3&\dots&\alpha_n
\\\alpha_1&\alpha_2&0&\dots&\alpha_n
\\\vdots&&&&\vdots
\\\alpha_1&\alpha_2&\alpha_3&\dots&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which I am not able to diagonalize ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\text{deg }\phi(P)\le n$ you can write
\begin{align}\phi(P) 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \color{red}{\phi(P)(\lambda_k)}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=0,j\neq k}^{n}\dfrac{X-\lambda_j}{\lambda_k-\lambda_j}}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \color{red}{A(\lambda_k) P(\lambda_k)}
\color{blue}{\Phi_k}
\end{align}

In particular, with $P$ being a Lagrange polynomial $\Phi_k$:
$$
\phi(\Phi_k) =A(\lambda_k) \Phi_k
$$
So this is a basis made of eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't get why you have a $\phi(A)(\lambda_k)=(AP)(\lambda_k)$. As $AA=BQ'+\phi(A)$, shouldn't it be $\phi(A)(\lambda_k)=A^2(\lambda_k)$ ?

Comment: $AP = BQ + \phi(A)$ and $B(\lambda_k)=0$ so $A(\lambda_k)P(\lambda_k) = 0 + \phi(A)(\lambda_k)$.

Comment: It's $AP=BQ+\phi(P)$

Comment: @Hippalectryon okay, I switched $A$ and $P$. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Last thing I'm not sure to understand : 'with $P$ being a Lagrange polynomial $\phi_k$:' isn't $P$ independent of $k$ ?

Comment: In the first equality, $P$ is any polynomial of degree $\le n$. Next, I take the particular case of $P = \Phi_k$ to prove that it is an eigenvector.